# How to create a simple button using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want to create a simple button in Javascript that, upon being clicked, it runs a simple alert. I understand you have to make the button in html, and then assign a function to it in Javascript, I just don't know how to.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: I bet google has a few examples.  People have created buttons using JS for over a decade.

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: Please show us the code you developed so far, so we can start from that code to discuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button id="btn">Alert</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert('hello');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be something as simple as this

```html
<button onclick="console.log('hello');">Press me</button>
```

Or it could be something a lot more complicated.

Really the thing to do it look up some javascript tutorials online.

http://www.codecademy.com/learn has some great free material taking you from knowing nothing to proficient enough to work it out yourself in not very long.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert('testing');
    });

    document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].append(btn);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myButton= document.createElement("BUTTON");
 document.body.appendChild(myButton);
```

This should work.